# How to calculate rolling standard deviation in 1 hour intervals across dates?

Tags: time-series

I have time series data of electricity consumption. I want to calculate rolling standard deviation of 1 hour intervals with window size of 10 i.e. I want to take values from 8-9AM for last 10 days and compute std() for that window, then compute it for 9-10 AM window across last 10 days and so on.

I tried below 2 approaches but these are not working:

```
df.groupby(df.index.time)['value'].rolling(10).std()
df.groupby([df.index.date, pd.Grouper(freq='1h')])['value'].std()
```